# Program that choose elements from interval from an array and print them to a new array in java

Tags: java, arrays

it's my first post here and I'll try to be precise in my question. The problem which i have to solve for a homework : 
We create an array and have to make a program that choose the elements with values from -2.99 to 2.99 and print them in new array. (JAVA)
I tried this :
import java.util.Arrays;

```
public class Task14 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double[] array = { -1.1, 4.567, 0.45, 7.77, 2.01, -15.998, -0.004, 2.99, 3.005 };
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if ((array[i] >= -2.99) && (array[i] <= 2.99)) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        double[] interval = new double[count];
        for (int index = 0; index < array.length; index++) {
            if ((array[index] >= -2.99) && (array[index] <= 2.99)) {
// and here's the drama - i can't find a solution how to match the elements from the two arrays
//I tried 
interval[index] = array[index];  
//or to make a new variable which takes the value from array[index] when it's in -2.99 : 2.99, but it doesn't work either :) 
            }
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(interval));
    }
}
```

Can I take a hint, please?

Comment: Hint: talk to your teacher.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to continue down this path of solving the problem (without using `ArrayList`), consider adding a `currentIndex` variable to keep track of what new index you are currently on. This can be incremented whenever you find a value within your range, like so:

```
double[] interval = new double[count];
int currentIndex = 0;
for (int index = 0; index < array.length; index++) {
    if ((array[index] >= -2.99) && (array[index] <= 2.99)) {
        interval[currentIndex] = array[index];
        currentIndex++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I needed :)

Answer (score 0):

```
 List<Double> filteredList = new ArrayList<Double>();

 for (double val : array) {
        if (( val>= -2.99) && (val <= 2.99)) {
        filteredList.add(val);
        }
    }

  Double arr[] =  (Double[]) filteredList.toArray();
```

you can add the data to an `arraylist` which can  then be converted to an `double` array.

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep of the index for `interval` array:

```
int intervalIndex = 0;
for(a : array) {
    if(Math.abs(a) <= 2.99) {
        interval[intervalIndex++] = a;
    }
}
```

If you are using java 8 and want to use streams, you can use the `filter` function and do:

```
double[] array = // ...
return Arrays.stream(array)
             .filter(d => Math.abs(a) <= 2.99)
             .toArray()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in a little space inefficient way:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
double[] array = { -1.1, 4.567, 0.45, 7.77, 2.01, -15.998, -0.004, 2.99, 3.005 };
double[] arrayNew = new double[array.length];
for (int i = 0,k=0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if ((array[i] >= -2.99) && (array[i] <= 2.99)) {
        arrayNew[k] = array[i];
        k++;
    }
}
```

Here I am using variable 'k' to index the current position of the elements.

You can also use Vectors instead of array and it will be space and time efficient.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
double[] array = { -1.1, 4.567, 0.45, 7.77, 2.01, -15.998, -0.004, 2.99, 3.005 };
Vector<Double> arrayNew = new Vector<Double>();
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if ((array[i] >= -2.99) && (array[i] <= 2.99)) {
        arrayNew.add(array[i]);
    }
}
```